# Why does my react page go back without the button being clicked?

Tags: reactjs, button, react-navigation

I have a bar at the top of my react page that displays the order number and I would also like it to contain a back button.

I have the following code but when I navigate to this page it flashes up and automatically goes back to the previous page without the button being pressed. Can someone please tell me what I have done wrong?

```
import React from "react";
import {  Link} from "react-router-dom";

class Messages extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoading: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
    const url =
      "myURL" +
      this.props.location.state.rollNumber;
    fetch(proxyurl + url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => this.setState({ data: data, isLoading: false }));
  }

  render() {
    const { data, isLoading } = this.state;

    if (isLoading) {
      return <p>Loading ...</p>;
    }

    if (data.length === 0) {
      return <p> no data found</p>;
    }
    
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="detailsBanner">
          <div className="orderID"> <strong>Order number: {this.props.location.state.orderId}</strong></div>
          <div className="returnToApps"><button onClick={this.props.history.goBack()}>return to all orders</button></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Try this - `onClick={this.props.history.goBack}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't execute the function inside the onclick

```
<button onClick={this.props.history.goBack}>return to all orders</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead use onClick={this.props.history.goBack} you can use the code below:

```
<div className="returnToApps">
    <Link to="/"}>return to all orders</Link>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Beceause since you wrote the code this way

```
<button onClick={this.props.history.goBack()}
```

when the component is mounted the function goBack() will be executed directly

it's like you put

```
{state.someArray.map(item => <span>Name :{item.name}</span>)} 

will render => 
Name: myName0
Name: myName1
Name: myName3
```

in the jsx, when you load the page you will see x times the Name and his values. It's executed directly.

Try to write this way

```
<button onClick={() => this.props.history.goBack()}
```

Or what UKS wrote.

This way, it will avoid the function to be launched directly when the component is mounted, and only be triggered when you click on it. Let me know if this helps